# segmentation fault when using HuggingFaceEmbedding

Tags: huggingface, llama-index

I have this code that I throwing me the error:"segmentation fault"

```
    import os
    import streamlit as st
    
    os.environ["REPLICATE_API_TOKEN"] = "my_token"
    
    from llama_index.llms import Replicate
    
    llama2_7b_chat = "meta/llama-2-7b-chat:8e6975e5ed6174911a6ff3d60540dfd4844201974602551e10e9e87ab143d81e"
    llm = Replicate(
        model=llama2_7b_chat,
        temperature=0.01,
        additional_kwargs={"top_p": 1, "max_new_tokens": 300},
    )
    
    from llama_index import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader
    from llama_index.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbedding
    from llama_index import ServiceContext
    
    embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbedding(model_name="BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5")
    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
        llm=llm, embed_model=embed_model
    )
    
    documents = SimpleDirectoryReader("data").load_data()
    index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
        documents, service_context=service_context
    )
    
    
    #index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
    
    # Get the query engine
    query_engine = index.as_query_engine(streaming=True)
    
    # Create a Streamlit web app
    #st.title("LLM Query Interface")
    query = st.text_input("Enter your query:")
    submit_button = st.button("Submit")
    
    if submit_button:
        # Query the engine with the defined query
        response = query_engine.query(query)
        st.write("### Query Result:")
        st.write(response)
```

if I disable embed_model code runs without problems.

I run the script via:

```
    streamlit run my_script.py
```

```
python --version
Python 3.9.7
```

I run this on Mac, Catalina, I have at least 250GB available memory. Please advise.

Comment: Please include the full traceback/segmentation fault.  What python version are you using?

Comment: I added python version. Not sure how I would provide traceback. Can you please advise?

Comment: traceback as in the Segmentation Fault error.  Kinda akin to the error message as posted in https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/5590  (which kinda relates to your issue, though possibly not the same... depending on the stacktrace)